# dynamically converting tiff images to jpg in php

Tags: php, tiff, imagemagick-convert

How to **dynamically Convert Tiff Images** to jpeg using PHP, and Imagemagic .pls help as im new to php programming

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick uses "convert" function for converting the image extension. As an example

```
convert rose.jpg rose.png
```

You have to call this command line method through a system call from your php page like,

```
system('convert rose.jpg rose.png');
```

Other options are available for destination/source location, resolution etc. Check this link for more details [Imagemagick Convert Command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php/)

Comment: I look forward to asking your service to convert "`x.jpg; rm config.php`"

Comment: Something like this...so that when client uploads an image if its tiff then this cmd will be invoked converted and displayed.        exec(convert inputFileDirectory/$inputfilename.tiff  outputFileDirectory/$outputFilename.jpg);

Comment: yes, some minor points like.. 
1. Check the imagemagick installed path, otherwise convert command will not work
2. use a quote when you pass the param in exec command.